# delete method on canvas tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Trying to delete a random shape on canvas by clicking the "remove rect" button created. but my method doesn't seem to work. I keep getting this error, must be small but I can't seem to find it.

> TypeError: removeRects() missing 1 required positional argument: 'canvas'

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()


class Recta:
    def __init__(self, height=60, width=80):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.create_buttons()
        self.canvas = Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.pack()

    def removeRects(self,canvas):
        my_rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,w,h,fill = "green")
        self.canvas.delete(my_rect)

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.frame = Frame(root, bg='grey', width=400, height=40)
        self.frame.pack(fill='x')
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame, text='Rect', command=self.randomRects)
        self.button1.pack(side='left', padx=10)
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame, text='Remove Rect', command=self.removeRects)
        self.button2.pack(side='left')

    def randomRects(self):
        w = random.randrange(300)
        h = random.randrange(200)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, w, h, fill= "green")


tes = Recta()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep track of the rectangles you are creating in a collection; then extract the `id` from the collection in order to remove a rectangle.

here, I created a list to aggregate the ids of the rectangle created: `self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, w, h, fill='green')` returns an id number that is stored in the collection.

Upon calling the `delete` method, the `id` from the last created rectangle is retrieved (and removed from the collection) and used to `remove` the rectangle from the `canvas`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
root = tk.Tk()

class Recta:

    def __init__(self, height=60, width=80):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.create_buttons()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.rects = []

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='grey', width=400, height=40)
        self.frame.pack(fill='x')

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Add Rect', command=self.randomRects)
        self.button1.pack(side='left', padx=10)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Remove Rect', command=self.removeRects)
        self.button2.pack(side='left')

    def removeRects(self):
        if len(self.rects) > 0:
            self.canvas.delete(self.rects.pop())

    def randomRects(self):
        w = random.randrange(300)
        h = random.randrange(200)
        self.rects.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, w, h, fill='green'))


tes = Recta()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the same code with a * import!

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()

class Recta:

    def __init__(self, height=60, width=80):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.create_buttons()
        self.canvas = Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.rects = []

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.frame = Frame(root, bg='grey', width=400, height=40)
        self.frame.pack(fill='x')

        self.button1 = Button(self.frame, text='Add Rect', command=self.randomRects)
        self.button1.pack(side='left', padx=10)
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame, text='Remove Rect', command=self.removeRects)
        self.button2.pack(side='left')

    def removeRects(self):
        if len(self.rects) > 0:
            self.canvas.delete(self.rects.pop())

    def randomRects(self):
        w = random.randrange(300)
        h = random.randrange(200)
        self.rects.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, w, h, fill='green'))


tes = Recta()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: import tkinter as tk
import random
root = tk.Tk()    whats tk.Tk() ??

Comment: whats the difference between from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()    and import tkinter as tk import random root = tk.Tk() whats tk.Tk()

Comment: `tk.Tk()` is calling the creation of a `Tk` object in the `tk` module - you imported `tkinter *`; I imported `tkinter as tk` which keeps the namespace tidy. Whan you `from tkinter import *`, all methods and classes of `tkinter` enter your namespace. when I `import tkniter as tk`, I must prefix calls to `tkinter` methods and classes with `tk.`

Comment: can you still do this method whilst using tkinter *

Comment: Yes you can - using your import method, and removing all the `tk.`prefixes will work; however, this is not the recommended way.

Comment: when i try to do it the other way i still get the same error

Comment: You must remove all the prefixes - see updated answer!