# trying to add shape using stack()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter-canvas

Trying to add and remove a circle using a stack(). Im getting an error which I'm unsure about. trying to add a circle in a random position and a random size. This is my stack class

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self):
    self.items = []

def is_empty(self):
    return self.items == []

def push(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)

def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()

def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

def size(self):
    return len(self.items)
```

This is my other class. I'm getting this error >>> AttributeError: 'Recta' object has no attribute 'stack'

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
from Stack import Stack

class Recta:

def __init__(self, height=60, width=80 ):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.create_buttons()
    self.canvas = Canvas(root)
    self.canvas.pack()
    stack = Stack()



def create_buttons(self):
        self.frame = Frame(root, bg='grey', width=400, height=40)
        self.frame.pack(fill='x')
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame, text='Oval', command=randomCircle)
        self.button1.pack(side='left', padx=10)
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame, text = "Remove Oval")
        self.button2.pack(side = 'left')

def randomCircle(self):
    w = random.randrange(300)
    h = random.randrange(200)
    self.stack.push(self.canvas.create_oval(0,0,w,h,fill= random.choice(self.colours)))
```

tes = Recta()
root.mainloop()

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the issue is and exactly what it is you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

in init it should be self.stack = Stack() not stack = Stack()

Comment: rookie mistake sorry. In order to do a remove function for this would you use pop() ?

Comment: i want to try remove the shape. In order to do that would I have to create another function which pops the shapes of the top of the stack ?

Comment: pop will remove the random shape that you pushed recently. Your current implement ion of pop should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works.

You really need to study [the code proposed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36786150/2875563) in order to be able to repeat it for various shapes and situations. :)

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)



class Recta:

    def __init__(self, height=60, width=80 ):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.create_buttons()
        self.canvas = Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.stack = Stack()        # <-- must be self.stack

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.frame = Frame(root, bg='grey', width=400, height=40)
        self.frame.pack(fill='x')
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame, text='Oval', command=self.randomCircle)    # <- must be self.randomCircle
        self.button1.pack(side='left', padx=10)
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame, text = "Remove Oval", command=self.remove_oval)     # <-- must have a command method to be able to do anything
        self.button2.pack(side = 'left')

    def randomCircle(self):
        w = random.randrange(300)
        h = random.randrange(200)
        self.stack.push(self.canvas.create_oval(0, 0, w, h, fill='blue'))

    def remove_oval(self):    # <-- must have a method to correspond to the command in button2
        try:
            a = self.stack.pop()
            self.canvas.delete(a)
        except:
            pass

root = Tk()
tes = Recta()
root.mainloop()
```

`remove_oval` can also be written as follows to take advantage of the `class Stack()` methods:

```
def remove_oval(self):
    if not self.stack.is_empty():
        self.canvas.delete(self.stack.pop())
```

Comment: I annotated the code to point out the most glaring mistakes. You seriously must take the time to read and understand this code, otherwise you are condemning yourself to ask a question every time a mistake occurs.